# Google Apps script Authorization from sidebar

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, google-docs, sidebar

Hi I have a script I am writing for a Google Docs template which includes a tutorial and some buttons to click for running scripts (some of which involve moving docs or folders and therefore require authorization).

The issue is when I try and run scripts through the sidebar, the authorization window doesn't pop up the way it does if I had made the request via a custom menu.  I would really like to use the sidebar instead of the menu as it looks a lot nicer and allows me to include pictures for the tutorial.  I have a button in the sidebar with this code:

```
<button class="create" onclick="google.script.run.addToDrive()">Add to Drive</button><br>
```

But to make this work I have to have a redundant menu that runs the same function first so it can be authorized.  Is there a better way?

thanks!

Comment: why not run any function from within the script editor 1st to trigger the auth?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using the new Docs and New Spreadsheets?
Can you paste some code?

When I want to force to appear the Authorization Window, sometimes I make a "foo function empty" as:

```
function foo(){
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Only new version of ss and docs have the ability to show a sidebar. Old version don't. Btw, how can such a client js function trigger an authorization process?  Could you elaborate on this pls?